# Location of the words in text

Tags: python, nltk

NLTK package of Python has a function **dispersion plot**, which shows location of chosen words in text. If there any numeric measure of such dispersion that can be calculated in python? E.g. I want to measure weather the word "money" is spread among the text or rather concentrated in one chapter?

Comment: I think you're talking about this? https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/draw/dispersion.html The metrics are right in the list comprehension points = [(x,y) for...

Comment: a dispersion plot, is a visual representation of word counts per text. it seems you want a metric over a text body, say on a paragraph level. does this sound right? what is your ultimate goal? I have some ideas but would like more information before I suggest an answer.

Comment: @Nathan McCoy I need some quantitative measure that shows weather the topic (some words) is represented only in one part of the text (e.g. chapter), which is bad, or spread over the whole document (which is good). So I need some quantitative measure of text quality which I can use for further data analysis.

Comment: @ MKesper Aren't these points just a coordinates of the particular words? I do not quite understand the code behind depression plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are multiple metrics that can be used to give a quantitative measure of what you are defining as informativeness of a word over a body of text.

## Methodology

Since you mention chapter and text as the levels you wish to evaluate, the basic methodology would be the same:

1. Break a given text into chapters
2. Evaluate model on chapter and text level
3. Compare evaluation on chapter and text level

If the comparison is over a threshold you could claim it is meaningful or informative. Other metrics on the two levels could be used depending on the model.

## Models

There are a few models that can be used.

### Raw counts

Raw counts of words could be used on chapter and text levels. A threshold of percentage could be used to determine a topic as representative of the text.

For example, if `num_word_per_chapter/num_all_words_per_chapter > threshold` and/or `num_word_per_text/num_all_words_text > threshold` then you could claim it is representative. This might be a good baseline. It is essentially a [bag-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) like technique.

### Vector Space Models

[Vector space models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) are used in Information Retrieval and Distributional Semantics. They usually used sparse vectors of counts or [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). Two vectors are compared with cosine similarity. Closer vectors have smaller angles and are considered "*more alike*".

You could create chapter-term matrices and average cosine similarity metrics for a text body. If the `average_cos_sim > threshold` you could claim it is more informative of the topic.

## Examples and Difficulties

Here is a [good example of VSM](http://www.johnwittenauer.net/language-exploration-using-vector-space-models/) with NLTK. This may be a good place to start for a few tests.

The difficulties I foresee are:

- Chapter Splitting
- Finding Informative Threshold

I can't give you a more practical code based answer at this time, but I hope this gives you some options to start with.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. I know that my question is rather general. In my case, I work with more the 1000 documents with different kinds of chapter names, so it will be difficult to cut the document in the chapters. I will cut it in several even pieces instead and as you suggest I will calculate percent for words in each piece. Then I will use Herfindahl–Hirschman Index to calculate the concentration over parts of text. I am not sure in how many pieces I need cut the documents, if they are 100-300 pages long. Is it good way to go?

Comment: You could use a type of Latent-Semantic Analysis, which could reduce the size of the data. I think what you are trying to do sounds fine, but you just need to see how tractable it is by testing with the data